# How to remove all stop words and single characters in Bigquery String column

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column in BigQuery table and I want to do some natural language pre-processing on it. Hence, I want to retain only characters from `a-z` and ignore others. I also want to ignore the words in the string that are single characters.

How can I do it best using big-query?

Sample input -

```
with data as (
select "efficacy!! and/or lasting affects whether community protected" as ip union all
select "n/a" as ip union all
select "this questions is un-clear information" union all
select "I m 84-years old!!!" union all select "none"
)
select * from data
```

so I have certain stop words like `a,am,the,none,na` etc.. which I want to remove from the text, I also dont want to keep retain single characters in the string.

Expected output -

```
efficacy and or lasting affects whether community protected
''
this questions un clear information
years old
''
```

The 2nd and 5th data points are blank because they contain stop words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [regexp_extract_all](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract_all) to extract all words and then filter them:

```
with data as (
  select "efficacy!! and/or lasting affects whether community protected" as ip union all
  select "n/a" as ip union all
  select "this questions is un-clear information" union all
  select "I m 84-years old!!!" union all
  select "none"
)
select STRING_AGG(word, " " ORDER BY offset)
from (
  select ip, word, offset
  from data, unnest(regexp_extract_all(ip, "[a-z]{2,}")) as word with offset
  where word not in ("am", "the", "none", "na", "is")
)
group by ip
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, can u make me understand the logic of `offset` here? Also, what does the `2` imply in the regex expression?

Comment: Offset is needed to keep the order of words when sentences are reconstructed back with STRING_AGG. `{2,}` imply "2 or more characters"

Answer (score 1):

Consider below alternative

```
with data as (
  select "efficacy!! and/or lasting affects whether community protected" as ip union all
  select "n/a" as ip union all
  select "this questions is un-clear information" union all
  select "I m 84-years old!!!" union all
  select "none"
), stop_words as (
  select 'am|the|none|na|is' list    
), pattern_to_remove as (
  select r'a-zA-Z' remove
)
  select trim(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(
      ip, r'[^' || remove || r']', ' '), r'(?:\b)(' || list || r'|[' || remove || r'])(?:\b)', ''), r'[ ]+', ' '
     )) as ip
  from data, stop_words, pattern_to_remove
```

looks a little overengineered, but has benefit of having generic query with stop words and to exclude chars to be controlled within the respective CTEs